# Why I can´t convert my server respond and got an error?

Tags: android, json

Im receiving some data from a web server.
Its only two parts a Name and an ID.
Dont know why it don´t worked tried it with jsonarray and with json object and both didnt worked.
I got a response but cant convert it into my data set up where i could use the respond in other parts of my programm. Dont know what I do wrong.

My repond code:

```
try {
        Data User = new Data();
        JSONObject UserName= new JSONObject();
        JSONObject user = (UserName.getJSONObject(res));
        User.setUserID(user.getInt("UserID"));
        User.setUserName(user.getString("UserName"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}


    //  System.out.println(getResponse);



@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(Config.KEY_UserEmail, UserEMail);
    params.put(Config.KEY_Userloggedstatus, Loggedstatus);
    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADDACCOUNTLOGIN, params);
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: "+ params);
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: SENDED!");
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: "+ res);
    return res;

}
```

Thats my server respond :

```
doInBackground: {"UserName":"Felix","UserID":6}
```

And thats the error:

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value {"UserName":"Felix","UserID":6} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

And last time its also :

```
 org.json.JSONException: No value for Result
```

How should I change my code to receive it right and could use the respond?

Comment: Have you tried UserName= new JSONObject(res)?

Comment: Sure tried everything think I do something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this. works for me.

```
try {
        String res = "{\"UserName\":\"Felix\",\"UserID\":6}";
        Data User = new Data();
        org.json.JSONObject user = new JSONObject(res);
        User.setUserID(user.getInt("UserID"));
        User.setUserName(user.getString("UserName"));
        System.out.println(User.getUserID());
        System.out.println(User.getUserName());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Wow thank you it worked. But I used my String res I got as response of doinbackround! Don´t know why but thought tried it before but it wont work. Now it worked fine and I got the response and can work with it.

Comment: hi@jayjohn,glad to hear this~Please accept this answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks :)